mTLS with go: client certificate not sent to server
I'm trying to establish a mTLS connection with the server being the Caddy admin-API and the client being go.
Certificates are set up and working - verified with curl.
There are plenty of explanations and code snippets out there explaining this setup in go, yet I always receive the error remote error: tls: certificate required
The error log server side is {"level":"debug","ts":1721118435.5978072,"logger":"admin.remote","msg":"http: TLS handshake error from ___:65411: tls: client didn't provide a certificate"}
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code for testing:
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    cert := flag.String("cert", "./cert.pem", "TLS client certificate in PEM format")
    key := flag.String("key", "./key.pem", "TLS client key in PEM format")
    flag.Parse()

    keypair, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(*cert, *key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    client := http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{
                Certificates: []tls.Certificate{keypair},
                MinVersion:   tls.VersionTLS13,
            },
        },
    }
    res, err := client.Get("https://caddy.influxdb.eco2web.de:2021/config/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}


Which signature algorithm is used for the certificate (check with openssl x509 -noout -text < cert.pem)? Run your curl command with -v; does it actually use TLS1.3?

@Peter: yes that server answers 1.3, and the alert it sent (116) only exists in 1.3. It also asks for Ed25519 and PSS, RSA1.5, ECDSA schemes with all 3 SHA2 plus the latter two with SHA1; that excludes only DSA which I doubt OP has and anyway would have failed in curl. Johnny: is your cert selfsigned? Check the issuer (not necessarily subject) is C = DE, O = BS-Systeme, OU = Caddy Admin client cert -- if your curl is built with OpenSSL (like many) it doesn't enforce correct issuer name as standards say, but I bet go does.

@dave_thompson_085, I understand that Go negotiates 1.3 as per the configuration. My suspicion is that curl negotiates 1.2 and can therefore use a cert with, say, SHA1 signature. Such a cert would be ignored by Go because it cannot be used with 1.3.

@Peter the signature algorithm is sha256WithRSAEncryption and it does indeed use tls1.3 both server and client enforce it

@dave_thompson_085 no it is not self-signed, but signed by my own CA - not publicly trusted.
The issuer is exactly that, as the caddy admin api expects this and only this certificate. I don't think curl uses openssl as curl --version lists libressl. Im running it on macOS

So both Side has correct chain of trust? On mutal authentication both parties needs to authenticate against it, so i am wondering why there is no ca cert, or intermidiate certs in the tls config. I only do this server side but, I got Always the chain of trust from the Client in the certificate Handshake record. CA + Client auth cert.

@Christoph you mean the chain of trust client side? I tried various things, without CA as in the example, but also loading the client cert that contained the CA cert as well. I also gave installing the CA on the server system a try but nothing changed.
This is actually what I expected, as the caddy admin-api can only be configured to accept specific certificates. I'm not sure if the chain of trust is validated.
The client on the other hand accepts the Server's cert as it is signed by Let's encrypt.

Lets recap on mutal authentication both parties needs to Verify the other side. so create a root ca (self Signed) create two certificates one for Server one for client. On server side you need to configure the CA as an trusted CA certificate and configure the Server that it use the Server certificate, same you need todo on client side, your TLS config is also missing the "ClientAuth". Use this as a reference how todo real mtls with Go https://github.com/haoel/mTLS

@Peter: now we know it's moot, but SHA1 cert signatures (not protocol signatures) can be used in 1.3 IF allowed by the peer which they are here; see 8446 p44. OP: LibreSSL is a fork of OpenSSL but I don't know if they changed this point. I do think it's very bad practice and misleading to name a CA 'client cert' unless this is actually self-signed (which note does NOT just mean you are the person who signed it; self-signed means the issuing keypair is the entity keypair).

I have the same problem and have tried to replace the GetClientCertificate function so that the client certificate I want is returned "unchecked". It seems to have accepted this so far, but unfortunately I am now getting the "tls - bad certificate" response from the server, even though the whole thing has been accepted as a valid client certificate via curl.
I have also entered all CA certificates under both RootCAs and ClientCAs.

Awesome, that solved my issue. I guess that for some reason caddys CertificateRequestInfo mismatches the certificate I use and it therefore never got sent.
